# Similar to "levels adjustment" brightness improvement with ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg, color-correction, filter

I'm composing a video from set of 16bit tiff pictures. The pictures are very dark, and needs to be brightened. Currently I'm applying `-vf "mp=eq2=1.0:1.0:0.3:1.0:1.0:1.0:1.0:1.0"`
filter to make pictures brighter, as said [here](http://www.mplayerhq.hu/DOCS/man/en/mplayer.1.html#VIDEO%20FILTERS), but they becomes too "faded".

I used to rescale their histogram with "levels adjustment" operation in image editor to make them brighter, but now I need to make a video, not a single image file. Also, preffered way of applying such operations to image - is to applying it to each color band separatly, because they have different brightness attributes initialy.

Can I do something similar with ffmpeg?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

[image: original]
[image: with curves filter]

You could possibly use the [curves filter](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#curves). It has a `lighter` preset:

```
ffmpeg -i input -vf curves=preset=lighter -c:a copy output
```

The red, green, and blue components can be adjusted separately. The following is the same as what the `lighter` preset uses:

```
curves=r='0.4/0.5':g='0.4/0.5':b='0.4/0.5'
```

Additionally you can make your own curves preset in Photoshop, export it as an `.acv` file, and then the curves filter can utilize it:

```
curves=psfile=/path/to/ps_curves_file.acv
```

Comment: Awesome, exactly what I needed

Comment: Do you know why I get a warning when trying to run the filter with the values that the `lighter` preset is supposedly using under the hood? `Only one point (at (0.100000;0.500000)) is defined, this is unlikely to behave as you expect.`